# Get class name along with package using log4j in Java

Tags: log4j

I have various test Class which contains logger steps for low level debugging across code.

Now I want to implement logger in such a way that current class name is displayed along with my logger info

Suppose if my AutTest.java code has `logger.info("This is logger")` then console should display my current class name along with logger.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the below line of code in Base class which is extended by child class

For only class name

```
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

OR
Package info will be displayed

```
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

Eg:
In my com.aut.AppTest.java 
logger.info("This is logger");

**OUTPUT 1:**
2015-12-29 15:15:15 INFO  AutTest     - This is logger

**OUTPUT 2:**
2015-12-29 16:16:16 INFO  com.aut.AutTest     - This is logger